# HTAccess Redirect specific URLs to new domain pages and then rest to Root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Having checked other questions and trying the suggested solutions, nothing has worked so far.

I'm trying to redirect certain URLs from the old-domain to URLs on the new-domain, not necessarily with the same page names. The rest of the URLs should be redirected to the root of the new-domain. This is what I've tried. The redirecting of all pages to the root of the new-domain works, just not the individual pages:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /travel/ferry.html http://www.new-domain.com/ferry/
RewriteEngine off
#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new-domain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix `Redirect` directive and `RewriteRule` directives as they come from different Apache modules and their order of execution might be unpredictable.

You may have your rules as this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# keep specific redirect here
RewriteRule ^travel/ferry\.html$ http://www.new-domain.com/ferry/ [L,NC,R=301]

# redirect rest of the URLs to root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new-domain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser or test after fully clearing browser cache.